# Will Monero need SegWit to implement the Lightning Network?

Tags: network, lightning-network

I have heard that many other coins need to implement SegWit to allow them to enable the Lightning Network. Is this something that Monero will have to do?

Comment: @JollyMort though the answer may be the same, I believe the question is different.